# adding text to a certain line in a doc using batch

Tags: json, batch-file

Alright, I need to add a line of text to a certain line in a `json` file

Example:

```
"Forge": {
        "name": "Forge",
        "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916"
        },
```

Into a existing `json` file at a certain line
Is it possible?

Comment: hey!!! why all the down-votes without comments? this is a reasonable question.

Comment: @user2867397  How is the "certain" line determined? by number? string search? Have you tried anything?  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo on&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set NLM=^



set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

set a=
set b=0
for /f "delims==" %%i in (file.txt) do (
   set /a b+=1
   set a=!a!%%i!nl!
   if "!b!" EQU "2" (set a=!a!"Forge": {!nl!        "name": "Forge",!nl!            "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916"!nl!        },!nl!)
)
(echo %a%)>>newfile.txt
```

to insert after line, see edit history ;)

Comment: only problem is, it puts the full output on the first line

Comment: what do you mean? I tested this on a file with 9 lines, specified line two, and newfile.txt contained 10 lines with the new one inserted in the right place. are you keeping all the empty lines? the empty lines enable storing the whole file in a variable. if you mean that it puts the inserted line all on one line, just add more sets in the if. please give me some more info on the problem and I'll revise the code.

Comment: see this http://pastebin.com/Vmb6fjsN i want to put the Forge thing on line 3, but when i try the output is all on 1 line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try using unix command "sed".
In your case use the following script will insert it in a 5th row:

```
sed -i '5i "Forge": { "name": "Forge", "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916" }' Json.file
```

Comment: batch file is a windows thing.

Comment: sed is OK for Windows, just change single to double quotes.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to install a new program to do this when he doesn't need to.

Comment: its to send to friends to install something so yeah can't really install a program to do it gotta just use vanilla batch

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper JSON parser in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) to add `foobar` for the value of the key `lastVersionId`:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use JSON;
my $json = <<EOF;
{
    "Forge": {
        "name": "Forge",
        "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916"
        }
}
EOF
my $perl_DS = decode_json $json;
$perl_DS->{Forge}->{lastVersionId} .= " foobar";
print encode_json $perl_DS;
```

Output :

```
$ perl script.pl | json_pp
{
   "Forge" : {
      "name" : "Forge",
      "lastVersionId" : "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.916 foobar"
   }
}
```